# POST request alerts that it was successful, but data is not sent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a JavaScript code that is supposed to send some data to a php file on the server. The JavaScript code gives an alert that the post was successful, but no data is on the php file. No errors show up in the console. What is the problem here?

Here is the code:

```
var data = "It works";
var url = "data.php";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
alert("It worked");
}
}
http.send(data);
```

Here is the site for the code:
http://mikeyrichards.freeiz.com/run.html

EDIT: A clarification, I only want the data to show up like a text file on the PHP. For some reason, my server cannot open text files, so I have to use PHP

Comment: here's the php code ?

Comment: Your `data` is a string, but to access in php you need a `key`/`value` pair

Comment: Your data is not URL-encoded. It should be in the form `param=value`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send data in key value format something like this

```
var data = "lorem=ipsum&name=test";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:

```
var data = 'data=It+works';
```

Then you can access it in the PHP script as `$_POST['data']`.

Don't forget to encode the space as `+` or `%20`. If you're generating the data dynamically, use `encodeURIComponent` to encode it properly:

```
var data = 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
```

Comment: I just want to open the php file like a text file. I do not want to process the data. Is there any way to just write the text into the php file instead?

Comment: Are you talking about a `PUT` request to replace a file on the server?

Comment: Yes, Sorry about the delay.

Comment: In that case, it should be `http.open("PUT", url, true)`. You'll need to check whether your server is configured to allow `PUT`.